# How to avoid creating Fragment object each time by switching fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment

I have only one activity in the app with 4 fragments which are switched bottom tab menu. So it's always one of 4 fragments on the screen at a time. Looks simple, but I'm asking myself why by switching fragments, new Fragment object must be re-created each time? This is from android documentation:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
// Replace the contents of the container with the new fragment
ft.replace(R.id.your_placeholder, new FooFragment());
// or ft.add(R.id.your_placeholder, new FooFragment());
// Complete the changes added above
ft.commit();
```

I could try storing references to fragments by my own and pick the ready object each time, but I found to examples of such fragment usage style, so it might be something wrong with it?

Comment: see my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

Create all the fragment once and use it or make your fragment object as a singleton to make it.

Singleton Example:

```
class MyFragment extends Fragment{
  private static MyFragment instance;

  public static MyFragment getInstance(){
    if(instance == null)
      instance = new MyFragment();

    return instance;
  }
}
```

create object fragment using by `MyFragment.getInstance();`

Now it won't create new Object every time.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the fragments in a ViewPager and just switch the ViewPager page.

Try this:

```
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    FragmentAdapter adapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new ExplorerFragment(), "Fragment1", false);
    adapter.addFragment(new NotificationFragment(), "Fragment2", false);
    adapter.addFragment(new HistoryFragment(), "Fragment3", false);
    adapter.addFragment(new AccountFragment(), "Fragment4", false);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            switch (id){
                case R.id.action_explorer:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                    final Menu bottomMenu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
                    final MenuItem targetMenuItem = bottomMenu.getItem(0);
                    targetMenuItem.setChecked(true);
                    break;
                case R.id.action_notification:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                    final Menu bottomMenu1 = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
                    final MenuItem targetMenuItem1 = bottomMenu1.getItem(1);
                    targetMenuItem1.setChecked(true);
                    break;
                case R.id.action_history:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                    final Menu bottomMenu2 = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
                    final MenuItem targetMenuItem2 = bottomMenu2.getItem(2);
                    targetMenuItem2.setChecked(true);
                    break;
                case R.id.action_account:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
                    final Menu bottomMenu4 = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
                    final MenuItem targetMenuItem4 = bottomMenu4.getItem(3);
                    targetMenuItem4.setChecked(true);
                    break;
                case R.id.action_search:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Edit1: How to create a NonSwipeableViewPager:

```
public class NonSwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setMyScroller();
    }

    public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setMyScroller();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }

    //down one is added for smooth scrolling

    private void setMyScroller() {
        try {
            Class<?> viewpager = ViewPager.class;
            Field scroller = viewpager.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
            scroller.setAccessible(true);
            scroller.set(this, new MyScroller(getContext()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class MyScroller extends Scroller {
        public MyScroller(Context context) {
            super(context, new DecelerateInterpolator());
        }

        @Override
        public void startScroll(int startX, int startY, int dx, int dy, int duration) {
            super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, 350 /*1 secs*/);
        }
    }
}
```

and then in your XML:

```
<com.project.Components.NonSwipeableViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation"/>
```

Comment: I know ViewPager only by implementing swipeable pages. Do you know if it possible to disable any kind of animation and swipe gestures and just make it replace fragments instantly?

Comment: Also I've seen that ViewPager keeps only limited number of fragments at a time. So if it has only cache of 3, then edge located fragments in my case will be still constantly recreated.

Comment: Yes. You just need to create a custom ViewPager component. I'll edit my post with the code @ArnieSchwarzvogel

Comment: You can try to remove that ViewPager limit with this:         viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);

Comment: Thanks for an idea. I could think that implementing custom ViewPager will lead me to some fragment object caching concept, which was intending to apply without ViewPager anyway, but I think I should give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `TAG` to your fragment while replacing and later retrieve it using `FragmentManager`'s `findFragmentByTag`:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
// Replace the contents of the container with the new fragment
Fragment fooFrag = fm.findFragmentByTag("foo-frag-tag");

if(fooFrag == null) {
    fooFrag = new FooFrag();
}

ft.replace(R.id.your_placeholder, fooFrag, "foo-frag-tag");
// or ft.add(R.id.your_placeholder, new FooFragment());
// Complete the changes added above
ft.commit();
```

Comment: Nice idea as well.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work - FragmentManager does not simply cache fragments, it is used only in combination with putFragment() which is a totally different story